# error_messages не переопределяет сообщения при валидации форм

Tags: django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не меняет код сообщения при валидации поля формы. Не могу понять почему. В документации я не нашел ответа на этот вопрос. Версия django 1.11. Так же не работает и когда я создаю форму через forms.Form. Помогите разобраться как правильно менять текст сообщения об ошибках. Так же прошу написать реальный пример кода который будет менять текст об ошибках. Спасибо!!!
Код формы:

```
class ContactModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GoodTestModel
        fields ='__all__'
        error_messages={'name':{'required': 'Выдать другое сообщение'}}
    name = forms.CharField()
```

Код шаблона:

```html
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Назад</a>
<p style="margin:0;">Простая форма</p>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_ul }}
    <input type="submit"  value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Код представления:

```
class GoodTestView(TemplateView, GeneralContext):
    template_name = 'catalog/test/simple__form.html'
    form = None
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form = ContactModelForm()
        return super(GoodTestView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GoodTestView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form
        return context
```

Comment: Так же был бы признателен если дадите реальный пример рабочего валидатора. Спасибо!

Comment: Я сейчас проверил - создал пустой проект с приложением, содержащим одну модель, одно представление, выводящее шаблон с этой формой, и одну модельную форму, использующую `error_messages` с типом `required`. У меня работает.

Comment: Какая версия django?

Comment: Проверил на 2.1.7 и 2.0.2.

Comment: А я в вопросе писал что версия django 1.11. Прошу проверь на этой версии.

Comment: Проверил на 1.11, тоже работает.

Comment: И у Вас код такой же как у меня в вопросе???

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что у вас поле `name` зачем-то явно объявляется в форме, а опция `Meta.error_messages` влияет только на поля сгенерированные из полей модели.

Если поле действительно нужно объявлять явно, то `error_messages` нужно передать в дескриптор поля:

```
name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Тысяча чертей!'})
```

Comment: Сергей, к сожалению явно или неявно, все не работает. Я пробовал по разному. Не понимаю почему, но у меня все равно не переопределяет. Скрин прикрепил к вопросу.

Comment: На скрине показана реакция браузера на атрибут поля ввода `required`, Django тут вообще не при чём. Исправить это можно только сделав  javascript-обработчик события submit формы.

Comment: Спасибо, огромное за качественную обратную связь и помощь! Вот в чем оказывается был подвох)